# Loop to sum up observation greater than subject in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set that looks like that

```
set.seed(100)
da <- data.frame(exp = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)), diam = runif(8, 10, 30))
```

For each row in the data set I want to sum up observations (diam) that are bigger than the diam in the specific row and are included in a level "exp".
To do that I made a loop:

```
da$d2 <- 0
for (i in 1:length(da$exp)){
 for (j in 1:length(da$exp)){
  if (da$diam[i] < da$diam[j] & da$exp[i] == da$exp[j]){
    da$d2[i] = da$d2[i] + da$diam[j]}
}
}
```

The lopp works fine and I got results

```
  exp     diam       d2
1   A 16.15532 21.04645
2   A 15.15345 37.20177
3   A 21.04645  0.00000
4   A 11.12766 52.35522
5   B 19.37099 45.92347
6   B 19.67541 26.24805
7   B 26.24805  0.00000
8   B 17.40641 65.29445
```

However, my real data set is much bigger than that (> 40000 rows and >100 exp levels) so the loop goes very slow. **I hope it is possible to use some function to facilitate calculations.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't require the initial order in the result you could do it quite efficiently like this:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(da), exp, -diam)
da[, d2 := cumsum(diam) - diam, by = exp]

da
#   exp     diam       d2
#1:   A 21.04645  0.00000
#2:   A 16.15532 21.04645
#3:   A 15.15345 37.20177
#4:   A 11.12766 52.35522
#5:   B 26.24805  0.00000
#6:   B 19.67541 26.24805
#7:   B 19.37099 45.92347
#8:   B 17.40641 65.29445
```

Using dplyr, that would be:

```
library(dplyr)
da %>%
  arrange(exp, desc(diam)) %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  mutate(d2 = cumsum(diam) - diam)
```

Comment: Very nice solution. You probably could skip ordering by `exp`, but the output won't be so nice. Or you could do `keyby = exp` instead.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks, I thought about that but then just left it as it was - I don't think it makes a huge difference