# Conditional sum data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I try to achieve the following which looks like [this question from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471432/conditional-sum-with-output-for-all-rows-in-r-data-table) but is not the same. I would like to sum and mean all the values from the same id if the date is larger than the date on that row. For row 3 this would mean: `61+61+57=179` and row 4: `61+57=118`
and for the mean for the same rows: `(61+61+57)/3`, `(51+57)/2`

or a weighted mean by an extra column.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT<-data.table(date=rep(c(2015:2020),3),
               value=round(runif(18,20,120)),
               id=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=6))

DT
    date value id
 1: 2015    52  a
 2: 2016    43  a
 3: 2017    34  a
 4: 2018    61  a
 5: 2019    61  a
 6: 2020    57  a
 7: 2015    35  b
 8: 2016    34  b
 9: 2017    43  b
10: 2018    67  b
11: 2019    47  b
12: 2020   106  b
13: 2015    25  c
14: 2016    64  c
15: 2017   100  c
16: 2018    32  c
17: 2019    76  c
18: 2020    41  c
```

I tried this:

```
DT[,sum_value:=sum(value[date>date[1]]),by=id]
```

But this doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do duplicate dates occur within one id?

Comment: There should be no duplicate dates within one id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicated dates per id and if you don't require the initial order, you can use:

```
setorder(DT, id, -date)
DT[, x := cumsum(value)-value, by = id]
```

To calculate the `mean` of previous dates, you could use:

```
DT[, z := (cumsum(value)-value)/(seq_len(.N)-1L), by = id]
```

Comment: I had the same line of thinking, nice one.

Comment: Thanks. And if it would not be a sum, but a mean or weighted.mean for instance. How would that work?

Comment: [Looks very familiar...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345867/loop-to-sum-up-observation-greater-than-subject-in-r/30346058#30346058)

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht, can you please update your question with an example of that? I'm not sure about the expected output

Comment: @DavidArenburg, oh that's indeed quite similar. Feel free to close it as a dupe.

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht, I updated my answer with an approach to calculate the mean

Comment: Thanks, I see it. But what I'm actually after is doing more complex calculations on the relevant rows. With relevant, I mean all rows of the same id with a larger date. Would you know another solution than the cumsum?

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht, I think it would be best for you to think of a more accurate description (and function example) of your problem and ask a new question since this was closed

Comment: @docendodiscimus You're right. I'll do that, thanks.